# Proof of a lemma that is needed to derive Stirling's approximation

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

How do I prove that $$\left\lvert \log(1+x)-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3} \right\rvert \le \frac{x^4}{4}$$?

(for $x \in (0,1) $)

We used this result to derive the first order Stirling formula.

Comment: Hint: Use the power series expansion for $\ln(1+x)$ centered at $x=0$ along with the alternating series remainder theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may prove first that for any $z\in(0,1)$

$$ 0\leq -\frac{1}{1+z}+1-z+z^2 \leq z^3 \tag{1} $$
holds. Since $(1+z)>0$, $(1)$ is equivalent to:
$$ 0\leq -1+(1-z)-z(1-z)+z^2(1-z) = z^3\leq z^3(1+z) \tag{2} $$
that is trivial. By integrating every term of $(1)$ with respect to $z$ over the interval $(0,x]$ we prove the original claim.